# ng-form with $setPristine()

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-form

```
<tr ng-form="fbForm_{{$index}}">
    <td><center><p ng-hide="fb.editMode">{{fb.clientId}}</p>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="clientId" ng-show="fb.editMode" required
               ng-model="fb.clientId"/></center>
        <span ng-show="fbForm_{{$index}}.clientId.$dirty && fbForm_{{$index}}.clientId.$error.required">Client Id is required.</span>
    </td>
    <td><center><p ng-hide="fb.editMode">{{fb.clientSecret}}</p>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="clientSecret" ng-show="fb.editMode" required
               ng-model="fb.clientSecret"/></center>
        <span ng-show="fbForm_{{$index}}.clientSecret.$dirty && fbForm_{{$index}}.clientSecret.$error.required">Client secret is required.</span>
    </td>
    <td style="width:10%">
        <p ng-hide="fb.editMode"><a ng-click="toggleEdit()" href="javascript:;">Edit</a> | <a ng-click="deletefacebook()" href="javascript:;">Delete</a></p>
        <p ng-show="fb.editMode"><a class="btn btn-primary simple_button"  ng-disabled="fbForm_{{$index}}.$pristine || fbForm_{{$index}}.$invalid" data-ng-click="save($index); fbForm_{{$index}}.$setPristine()" href="javascript:;">Save</a> | <a class="btn btn-primary simple_button" ng-click="cancel($index,fb.fbConfigId)" href="javascript:;">Cancel</a></p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/LnnJQj1WwQaxLjlIWXq2?p=preview

for ng-disabled I am able to use {{$index}}
Getting syntax error in pristine function form name.

Comment: outline your problem better instead of just showing code

Comment: @bhavin Given information is not enough to answer your question. please let us know your problem in detail.

Answer (score 1):

`ngDisabled` and `ngClick` directives expect expressions, so it should be something like this:

```
ng-disabled="this['fbForm_' + $index].$pristine || this['fbForm_' + $index].$invalid" 
ng-click="save($index); this['fbForm_' + $index].$setPristine()"
```

Comment: Thank you little two lines piece of a cake :)

Comment: No problem, feel free to accept the answer if it helps.

Comment: How  can I replace ng-form="fbForm_{{$index}}"  to ng-form="fbForm_{{$index+(parseInt({{fbSize}}) * parseInt({{currentPage}} - 1))}}" ?

Comment: `ng-form="fbForm_[$index+(parseInt(fbSize) * parseInt(currentPage - 1))]"`

Comment: Sorry it won't work out so i changed it to fbForm_[$index+(parseInt({{fbSize}}) * parseInt({{currentPage}} - 1))]  coz those are my scope variables but again one more problem when i inspect that element shows like this fbForm__[$index+(parseInt(10) * parseInt(2 - 1))]  hadn't executed parseInt method.

Comment: I tried this "fbForm_{{$index + ( fbSize * (currentPage - 1))}}" and it's working fine.

Comment: Although a very bad written question, a masterpiece answer. Thanks! Accept his answer!!